# How to fix a element (have example) on the screen using jquery /css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

[Example](http://www.chicco.com/) In this webs you can see that there is an "follow us , facebook " on the left hand side.

When you slide the screen up or down, it follow your screen.

I wonder how to implement this or are there any exist jquery plugin to do such function ? Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#myElement {
    position:fixed;
    top:50px;
    left:0px;
}
```

The element will be positioned relative to the browser window and scrolling / resizing won't influence it

Answer (score 0):

You just have to use some styling set position as `position:fixed;` . you can use css rules for it too, here is a example.

**Inline styling**

```
<div style="position:fixed; top:100px; left:0px;">
   your content
</div>
```

**Using css**

```
<html>
    <style>
        #element {
            position:fixed; top:100px; left:0px;
        }
    </style>
    <body>
        <div id="element">
            your content
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Inline styles are also CSS, by the way